# Access to Facebook Streamers Data

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to leverage the Facebook API to gather data on streamers on Facebook Gaming (i.e., live broadcast status, view count, etc.).

I can find the data I'm looking for on the Facebook site at https://www.facebook.com/gaming/browse/streamers/?q=QUERY-HERE. Is there a way to access this data without scraping the Facebook frontend?